# Get column's last row using [-1]?

Tags: python, pandas

I have places of code like this all over that seem to work fine.

```
df['FAST_MA'] = df['close'].rolling(5).mean()
lfma = df['FAST_MA'][-1]
```

However in other places, I get a generic error when I try:

```
  ERROR - error from callback <function on_message at 0x12619cc20>: -1.0
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/websocket/_app.py", line 346, in _callback
    callback(self, *args)
  File "file.py", line 177, in calculate
    lfma = df['FAST_MA'][-1]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 868, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/numeric.py", line 375, in get_value
    loc = self.get_loc(k)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/numeric.py", line 436, in get_loc
    tolerance=tolerance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2659, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 382, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Float64HashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 388, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Float64HashTable.get_item
```

and then I have to do something like this instead.

```
# df['FAST_MA'] = df['close'].rolling(5).mean()
lfma = df['FAST_MA'].iloc[-1]
```

What are the differences and how could `df['FAST_MA'][-1]` break in unexpected scenarios?

Comment: I'd recommend having a read of the docs for slicing and indexing : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try similate problem, selecting with `DatetimeIndex` working nice for both ways:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'close': list(range(4))}, index=pd.date_range('2019-10-01', periods=4))
print (df)

df['FAST_MA'] = df['close'].rolling(2).mean()
print (df)
            close  FAST_MA
2019-10-01      0      NaN
2019-10-02      1      0.5
2019-10-03      2      1.5
2019-10-04      3      2.5

print (df['FAST_MA'][-1])
2.5
print (df['FAST_MA'].iloc[-1])
2.5
```

But for default `RangeIndex`:

```
d = {'close': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [3, 4, 5]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['FAST_MA'] = df['close'].rolling(2).mean()
print (df)

print (df['FAST_MA'].iloc[-1])
   close  col2  FAST_MA
0      1     3      NaN
1      2     4      1.5
2      3     5      2.5

print (df['FAST_MA'][-1])
KeyError: -1
```

This error means pandas looking for index value `-1` instead last position and because not exist raise `KeyError`.

Most general solution is use methods [`Series.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html) or [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html).

Also if want select in `DataFrame` also is possible use [`DataFrame.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html), [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df.iat[-1, df.columns.get_loc('FAST_MA')]
df.iloc[-1, df.columns.get_loc('FAST_MA')]
```

Comment: Wow! That's it. Yes I have some data where index is timestamp and some data where index is float/integer. So is it better practice to just always use `iloc[-1]` because it is more compatible?

Comment: for range index use `[:]` eg `df[-1:]` will return the final row for a range index.

Answer (score 0):

```
dataframe['feature_name'].iloc[-1]
```

Accessing the last element without using `iloc` is not applicable i.e., while using negative index